# How to remove specific data in Google Docs

Tags: regex, text, google-docs, find-replace

I can't wrap my head around regular expressions. Please provide a copypaste solution.

**Task**

I have a text document that used to be subtitles. It contains timestamps and a lot of linebreaks. I want to strip out timestamps and linebreaks and get a homogenous blob of text.

**What I have**

```
0:04:10.700,0:04:11.360
but

0:04:11.360,0:04:15.680
but it was plenty big you know the silo itself would have easily been

0:04:16.180,0:04:18.420
as wide as this room is

0:04:18.420,0:04:23.200
and perhaps larger and many, many, story's tall, you know because it was nested underground
```

**What I want to get**

> but but it was plenty big you know the silo itself would have easily
>   been as wide as this room is and perhaps larger and many, many,
>   story's tall, you know because it was nested underground

Notice that after removing a linebreak a space has to be entered before every line of text for it to be separate from the preceding text.

Thank you!

Comment: Please edit your question and put the code (not the image) in there.

Comment: Copy sample of text and paste it in your post.

Comment: Added samples. Sorry for inconsistent formatting. Blockquote didn't handle linebreaks properly.

Comment: What programming language are you using?

Comment: Your solution worked like a charm. Did you delete it?

Comment: Yes. What programming language are you using?

Comment: I’m using regex for search and replace.

Answer (score 0):

You might use:

[`\n*\d+:\d+:\d+\.\d+,\d+:\d+:\d+\.\d+\n(.*)`](https://regex101.com/r/2Oaa2C/1)

This would match

```
\n*              # Zero or more newlines
\d+:\d+:\d+\.\d+ # Match pattern using one or more digits, colon and dot
,                # Match comma
\d+:\d+:\d+\.\d+ # Match pattern using one or more digits, colon and dot
\n               # Match new line
(.*)             # Capture any character zero or more times (group 1)
```

Replace with group 1 and a white space `$1`

Comment: Thank you for providing details that allow me to understand regex.